# Micropython/Circuitpython - ESP32-Cam - How to download images taken onto computer?

Tags: camera, esp32, micropython

*Newbie alert*

I have code that takes a picture with the camera on the ESP32 but then that picture is in the flash memory and I don't know how to retrieve it. How do I get it onto my computer using micropython or circuitpython?

Comment: Well, the *"normal"* way would probably be to join a common wifi network with your PC and transmit via a socket, but it depends how your ESP32 and PC are connected, e.g. you may have a serial link.

Comment: I do have a serial connection now for debugging but eventually it wouldn't be. Only through wifi would be the goal. Would there be a way using socket to upload each images as they are taken without going through saving it locally on the flash memory or MicroSD card first? Because I assume saving them everytime before uploading them would kill either of those storages pretty quickly...?

Comment: as your question is very general, my answers will be also very generic: Create web server, or  FTP server on micropython device to access storage

Comment: How are you uploading your code to the ESP32? Does the ESP32-Cam firmware include [WebREPL](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp32/quickref.html#webrepl-web-browser-interactive-prompt)?

Comment: @nekomatic Uploading via Thonny using the REPL

Comment: The [Thonny wiki](https://github.com/thonny/thonny/wiki/MicroPython) says *You can upload / download data and library files and directories via respective commands in the file browser (View => Files) via files' context menu (opened by right-clicking on a file).* Does that work?

Comment: @nekomatic Yes, I figured it out today actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the Thonny wiki](https://github.com/thonny/thonny/wiki/MicroPython) says:

> You can upload / download data and library files and directories via
> respective commands in the file browser (View => Files) via files'
> context menu (opened by right-clicking on a file).

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote your code in Circuit Python you can make the esp32-cam connected to a wifi hotspot and transfer...  via http or mqtt as you whish.

But if you manage to get a picture from the camera WITH circuit python then you need to share how you achieved that!

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. The only library I know for this board+camera is from Lemariva using Micropython.